# Drools: How to call a subprocess in another jar?

Tags: java, drools, bpmn, kie

Take the following bpmn. It [attempts to] calls another process `HelloWorld.HelloWorld`. The `HelloWorld.HelloWorld` subprocess very similar, it just contains a tasks with a sysout. The bpmn for this is in another jar.

When attempting to invoke the digram below, we get the following:

```
ERROR [org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.SubProcessNodeInstance] (default task-1) Could not find process HelloWorld.HelloWorld
```

Both bpmn are in the same package, just different jar files. Is there a way to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Are both jars on the classpath? Does it make a difference if the second process is in a different jar and the package names are different?

Comment: Yes both are on the class path As I can load classes from the second jar. It doesn't work if things are in a different package either